# How to format datetime most easily in PHP?

Tags: php, time

To change `2009-12-09 13:32:15` to `09/12/2009`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here:

```
 echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime('2009-12-09 13:32:15'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to get the timestamp of the first date, and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert it to a string using the format you want.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2009-12-09 13:32:15');
echo date('d/m/Y', $timestamp);
```

And you'll get :

```
09/12/2009
```

---

**[edit 2012-05-19]** Note that **`strtotime()`** suffers a couple of possibly important limitations:

- The format of the date must be `YYYY-MM-DD`; it might work in some other cases, but not always !
- Also, working with [**UNIX Timestamps**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), as done with `date()` and `strtotime()` means you'll only be able to work with dates between 1970 and 2038 *(possibly a wider range, depending on your system -- but not and illimited one anyway)*

Working with the [**`DateTime`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is often a far better alternative:

- You can use either [**`DateTime::__construct()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) or [**`DateTime::createFromFormat()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a **`DateTime`** object -- the second one is only available with PHP >= 5.3, but allows you to specify the date's format, which can prove useful,
- And you can use the [**`DateTime::format()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to convert that object to any date format you might want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) method.

```
print date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2009-12-09 13:32:15"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $long_date = '2009-12-09 13:32:15';

 $epoch_date = strtotime($long_date);

 $short_date = date('m/d/Y', $epoch_date);
```

The above is not the shortest way of doing it, but having the long date as an epoch timestamp ensures that you can reuse the original long date to get other date format outputs, like if you wanted to go back and have just the time somewhere else.